# Laravel's blade master.layout won't display styles

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm facing a weird problem with layouts. It seems that the master layout will output a empty:

```
<style></style>
```

at the end of

```
<head></head>
```

overriding my

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

As it is show in the chrome console:

[image]

The code is very simple, my Master View is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Form Console Master Pages</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='content'>
            <div id="top">
                <h3>Video Game Consoles are pretty awesome! </h3>
                <p>This is a database of Videogames Consoles</p>
            </div>
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the index view is :

```
@extends('layouts.consoles')
@section('content')
    {{ $data }}
@stop
```

As the console show, an empty style is applied to the view. I have no idea where that last empty style tag is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your css link with the URL::asset

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('main.css') }}">
```

**Note `URL::asset` means your `project/public/` directory.

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately the style is still not being applied. It does fix the stylesheet URL thou. You can sea picture of the chrome elements in here: http://postimg.org/image/f2jyb37tv/

Comment: Have you already check from element inspector? @OmarGonzalezRocha

Comment: yep, This is a picture of the element inspector: http://postimg.org/image/f2jyb37tv/

Comment: @OmarGonzalezRocha You need to save main.blade.php (Have you saved with .blade.php ?)

Comment: yeah, double checked that before

Comment: Some of your extension can be embed empty `<style>` . To sure it please disable all of your extension and check again. And Test in another browser as well @OmarGonzalezRocha

Comment: Actually I made a new test project and the Views are working as intended... I really don't know whats going on with that other project, may be a bug.  If you don't mind telling me I can disable all my extension, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Open your chrome with private mode(Ctr+Shift+N) and test your website.@OmarGonzalezRocha

Answer (score 0):

You need t add `@yield('styles')` after your styles and before `</head>`